# Configuring Jenkins with a Git Reposiotry containing multiple projects

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

We have migrated from SVN to GIT and our repository structure has many projects in one single repository(not using submodules).

I would like to configure Jenkins on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with GitHub so that it checks out the subfolders from the reopository.

Say we have a repository and inside we have folders A,B corresponding to maven projects

I would like to set Jenkins' tasks for A and B.

Would it be possible ? or do i have to use submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMMO I think this is not posible for the simple reason that is not posible to clone a subdirectory of a GIT repository. And this is not posible because the integrity of any client-side repo would be compromised.

This is a common misunderstanding when you come from subversion, my opinion is that you sould migrate every project in his own GIT repository. And then use submodules to compose bigger super-projects.

Comment: well i am perfectly aware that you can't clone a sub-directory but was taking my chances :) thanks for the asnwer